# Invalid or unsupported protocol version error after insert several times in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Tomcat starts working normally and after the services add data to cassandra several times, I get an unsupported version error. The error is as follows;

> com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.ProtocolError: Invalid
>   or unsupported protocol version (0); supported versions are (3/v3,
>   4/v4, 5/v5-beta)  at
>   com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.ProtocolError.copy(ProtocolError.java:52)
>     at
>   com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:148)
>     at
>   com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.process(CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.java:59)
>     at
>   com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.process(CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.java:31)
>     at
>   com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:208)
>     at
>   com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession.prepare(CqlSession.java:145)

Comment: What version of Cassandra and driver are you using? Most likely your using too old of a driver for the version of Cassandra you are running.

Comment: cql version= 3.4.4
release version =3.11.4
Native protocol version =4
datastax java driver version = 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

With cassandra 3.0 and datastax driver v4, adding these parameters below in the driver config solved the same issue :

```
advanced.protocol {
   version = V4
}
```